# Prove that $m^*$ is countably additive on the family of open subsets of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Prove that $m^*$ (Lebesgue outer measure) is countably additive on the family of open subsets of $E=[0,1]$.

Lebesgue outer measure $m*$ of an union of countable number of open intervals $(a_1, b_1),(a_2,b_2),\ldots$ in $E$ is defined to be $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (b_i-a_i)$. I have already proved that any open subset of $[0,1]$ is union of a countable number of open intervals.

Consider an at most countable family $\{U_i\}_{i=1,2,\ldots}$ of open sets from $E$. Each set $U_i$ is an union of an at most countable family $(a_1^i,b_1^i),(a_2^i,b_2^i),\ldots$ of open intervals from $E$.

$$m^* \Big(\bigcup_i U_i \Big )=m^* \Big(\bigcup_i \bigcup_j (a^i_j,b_j^i) \Big)= m^* \Big(\bigcup_{i,j} (a^i_j,b_j^i) \Big)=\sum_{i,j} (b_j^i-a^i_j)=$$

$$=\sum_i \sum_j (b_j^i-a^i_j)=\sum_im^*(U_i)$$

My questions are:

1) Is the above argument correct?

2) How can one make my notation more rigorous (I know it is far from perfect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically correct as far as I can tell but you should make your hypotheses of mutually disjoint more explicit.  Also, what you are talking about is not "sums" but rather infinite series, and in principle for infinite series you need to be careful with the order of summation. This is easily fixed though.

Just make sure you mention that the sets are disjoint (additivity is certainly not true without it) and also that positive series are always absolutely convergent. For absolutely convergent series the order of summation is immaterial almost by definition.

Comment: I would be glad if you tell me how to fix this and I will accept it as an answer. Thank you.